# How to select the value of a variable in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, select-into

I'm new to Oracle. How can I set this variable and show its value?

```
declare nextId number;
begin  
        select HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE.nextval into nextId from dual;      
        select nextId from dual;
end;
```

It complains that an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement.

Answer (score 14):

If you only wanted to know the sequence's next or current value, 
you could simply use sql query:

```
SELECT HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE.nextval FROM dual;
SELECT HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE.currval FROM dual;
```

As to know how to proceed in pl/sql (before 11g):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
     nextId NUMBER;
BEGIN
     SELECT HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE.nextval INTO nextId FROM dual;
     dbms_output.put_line(nextId);
END;
```

Since 11g: it is more simplified sequence to use in plsql as:

```
SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
     nextId NUMBER := HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE.nextval;
BEGIN
     dbms_output.put_line(nextId);
END;
```

or simply

```
BEGIN
     dbms_output.put_line(HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE.nextval);
END;
```

More details:[Click here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=507)

Comment: +1 But since 11g you can directly access sequences in PL/SQL.  You can replace line 5 with `nextID := HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE.nextval;`.

Answer (score 8):

In a pl/sql block, you cannot write an SQL statement like

```
select nextId from dual;
```

That is why it is showing you an error. By the way you do not need this statement altogether. To display it as an output you should use -

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nextId);
```

To be able to display it you need to write the below statement before the declare block -

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

Comment: Sometime someone want to return a variable in row or rows not just print it